# Show that the quotient group $G/N$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $H$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $N\mathrel{\lhd}G$ a normal subgroup of $G$, and $H\leq G$ a subgroup of $G$. Suppose that $|H|$ and $|N|$ are relatively prime (*i.e.*, $\gcd(|H|,|N|)=1$). Show that the quotient group $G/N$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $H$.

I am trying to show that there is an injective homomorphism $\varphi:H\rightarrow G/N$ , but I have no clue for the next step.

Comment: Do You mean $N \triangleleft G$ instead of $H \triangleleft G$? And also $G/N$ instead of $G/H$? as $G/H$ may not be a group.

Comment: Hint. Think about what the natural homomorphism from $G$ to $G/N$ does to $H$. Can it send anything other than the identity to the identity?

Comment: The second isomorphism theorem says $HN/N \cong H/(H \cap N)$. Here $H \cap N$ is trivial as $(|H|,|N|)=1$. So then $HN/N \cong H$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  Show that $HN$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $N$.  Prove that, under the canonical projection $G\to (G/N)$, the subgroup $HN$ of $G$ is mapped onto a subgroup of $G/N$ isomorphic to $H$ (this subgroup is clearly, $HN/N$).  More generally, we have $HN/N\cong H/(H\cap N)$.